# Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, wpf

I have data Visitor in listview.
my xaml is

```
<ListView x:Name="listVisitor"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Height="582" Margin="110,65,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="924"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />`
<Button Content="Delete Visitor" Name="Delete" Foreground="white"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="236,674,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="310" Height="30" Background="#FF1CA0B7" Grid.Column="1"
        Click="Delete_Click"/>`
```

I already make connection to database and create code to delete data visitor

**Code:**

```
private void Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`
{
    if (listVisitor.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        var connectionString = new ConnectionString();
        var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ViMS_LOCAL());

        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)listVisitor.SelectedItem;
        string visitorno = drv.Row[0].ToString();

        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete FROM dbo.[Visitor.Profile] Where VisitorNo=@VisitorNo");
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VisitorNo", visitorno);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        BindData();

        }
    }
```

[image: Visitor table]

It display error ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.
How to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `Connection` property of the `SqlCommand` object before calling `ExectueNonQuery()`. For example:

```
conn.Open()
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete FROM dbo.[Visitor.Profile] Where VisitorNo=@VisitorNo");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VisitorNo", visitorno);
cmd.Connection = conn; // <- Set the connection
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

or you can pass it in the constructor:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                    "Delete FROM dbo.[Visitor.Profile] Where VisitorNo=@VisitorNo", 
                     conn);
```